# Nginx seemingly not allowing use of Regex in location directive

Tags: regex, nginx

My goal is to apply a location block to the URI: `/api/endpoint.json`

The following location directive in the config properly matches it: `location ~ /api/`

The following location directive doesn't match it: `location ~ ^/api/`

And neither does the following when I simply apply a capture group: `location ~ /(api)/`

Is there something subtle that I'm missing?  Thanks!

Comment: I'll note that this is Nginx v1.3.14

Comment: Are there any other location blocks that begin `location ^~ `?

Comment: No.  All the rest are simple string comparisons.